# Thunderbird logs a lot (calendar) into journal taking up space

Tags: thunderbird, ubuntu-18.04, lightning

While looking at my journalctl -b (on Ubuntu 18.04) entries a substantial amount of them are from thunderbird.desktop and formatted in ics (calendar/lightning). I don't know why thunderbird logs so much and I would like to stop it. How do I set log level? A lot of the info out there seems to be outdated.

Comment: According to [MailNews:Logging](https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews:Logging) the log level is in environmental variable `MOZ_LOG`, where 0 = Disabled and 1 = Error.

Comment: Yes, but it is not set to anything.

Comment: Try to set it to `0` to see if it works.

Comment: @harrymc yes I tried it but I still get logs.

Comment: Perhaps you should post this query in the Thunderbird forums.